# How can one inject the sqlite3 keyword DISTINCT into an Android ContentProvider's query?

Tags: android, sqlite, distinct, android-contentprovider

I have an SQL statement that I can use to return distinct rows from my Android sqlite3 database and I would like to pass it through a `ContentProvider`'s query.

For example:

```
select lastName from peopleTable where upper(lastName) like upper("%smith%");
```

needs to be

```
select DISTINCT lastName from peopleTable where upper(lastName) like upper("%smith%");
```

Is there a clean way to pass the extra keywords to the select statement?

Comment: Are you implementing the `ContentProvider`? Are you querying the `ContentProvider`? In other words, is the `DISTINCT` keyword inside the `ContentProvider` implementation, or are you trying to pass one into an existing `ContentProvider`, or something else?

Comment: If you're accessing an existing ContentProvider, the only direct SQL you can modify is the selection string (where clause), and order by statements. Your best bet is to see if that content provider has a URI that gives you a DISTINCT dataset. I suppose if you know the underlying table structure, you could also try to fiddle with a subquery in the where clause to give you a distinct dataset. I wouldn't recommend it though as the owner of that ContentProvider is free to modify the table/field names and render your subquery useless.

Comment: I have the ContentProvider, but I wanted to treat it as if it were a generic CP (i.e., some other owner).  What I finally did was create a GROUP BY clause that provided the effect of DISTINCT.  I then encoded it into the ORDER BY clause (sortOrder).  Then inside the CP, I parsed it out and issued it to the GROUP BY parameter of the DB query.  I probably should simply bypass the CP and issue the DB query directly.  Either way, I am cheating on my original intention.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what I would call a "Good Idea", but depending on the CP, you can modify your projection such that the first entry in the projection is "DISTINCT Column" instead of just "Column". This seems to work as long as the `ContentProvider` is backed by a database and no modifications are made to your projection. I will re-iterate though, that this may not be the best future-proof idea as this "feature" isn't documented and more a matter of how queries are put together with the `SQLiteDatabase` class. If you know how the `ContentProvider` was built, then you can tell up-front whether or not this will work.

Comment: very clever!  I like it, but I don't think I will use.  As you admit, it isn't future-proof.